# How to compare a list of words against a list of sentences in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have this PostgreSQL table for storing words:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('processed_words_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
)

insert into words (words)
VALUES ('while swam is interesting');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trademarks
(
   id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trademarks_id_seq'::regclass),
   trademark character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
)
```

Into table `trademarks` I will have thousands of registered trademarks names.
I want to compare words stored into `words` table keyword do they match not only for a words but also for word which is a in a group of words. For example:

I have a keyword `while swam is interesting` stored into `words.keyword`. I also have a trademark `swam` located in `trademarks.trademark` I have a word match so I want to detect this using SQL. How I can implement this?

Comment: with agood server you could cross join bith tables and try the like aproach, eve with a fulltext search will have the same problem, you could use dynamic sql and build a regular expression

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a task for full text search data types and functions, it would be something like this:

```
select w.id, w.keyword, t.trademark 
from words w
inner join trademarks t on w.keyword::tsvector @@ t.trademark::tsquery;
```

[working example here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Vj1x4KuV2cpfwZ2wVkSrX/1)

[In docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-DOCUMENT)

a more flexible query, if trademark field contains multiple words

```
select w.id, w.keyword, t.trademark 
from words w
inner join trademarks t on w.keyword::tsvector @@ 
regexp_replace(t.trademark, '\s', ' | ', 'g' )::tsquery;
```

where pipe symbol represents logical "or" and could be replaced by other operand according to your needs.
[Example of this here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Vj1x4KuV2cpfwZ2wVkSrX/2).
Of course indexing will be needed to speed up searches,
[check](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html) for text search index creation.

Another example, avoiding some special characters (in this case parenthesis) and trailing spaces in tsquery and also considering the posibility of multiple words, as pointed out in comments

```
select w.id, w.keyword, t.trademark 
from words w
inner join trademarks t on regexp_replace(w.keyword,'\(|\)', ' ', 'g' )::tsvector 
@@ regexp_replace(regexp_replace(trim(t.trademark),'\(|\)', ' ', 'g' )
, '\s+?(?=[a-zA-z])', ' | ', 'g' )::tsquery;
```

you have to take into account that tsquery is a logical sentence and there are some special characters to avoid, check the official docs on
[tsquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY)

Comment: I wanted to add something about clustering by a GIN/GiST index on a generated tsvector column in the source table, but it turns out it was already almost word-for-word [in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#:~:text=use%20a%20stored%20generated%20column) you linked. So I'll just leave an upvote and repeat that it's very useful.

Comment: I tried the second example but I get `ERROR:  no operand in tsquery: "Google | "
CONTEXT:  parallel worker
SQL state: 42601`

Comment: For the first one I get `ERROR:  syntax error in tsquery: "Caterpillar(CAT)"
SQL state: 42601`

Comment: Second example splits multiple querying words (space separated) by an operand, "or" in this case. So input field should have multiple words. On the syntax error for query word "Caterpillar(CAT)" probably is needed to escape those parenthesis, I'll check.

Comment: Added another query avoiding parenthesis but other special characters should be considered since tsquery is a logical sentence.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a trademark exists in the list of keywords in the words table, you can use the LIKE operator in a SELECT statement. For example:

```
SELECT keyword
FROM words
WHERE keyword LIKE '%swam%';
```

This will return any keywords that contain the word "swam", including the example keyword "while swam is interesting".

If you want to find exact matches for a trademark in the words table, you can use the = operator instead of LIKE:

```
SELECT keyword
FROM words
WHERE keyword = 'swam';
```

This will only return keywords that are exactly "swam", without any additional words before or after it.

You can also use the IN operator to check if a trademark exists in the words table:

```
SELECT keyword
FROM words
WHERE keyword IN ('swam');
```

This will return any keywords that are exactly "swam".

Note that in all of these examples, the trademarks table is not used. If you want to compare the keywords in the words table with the trademarks in the trademarks table, you can use a JOIN clause in your SELECT statement. For example:

```
SELECT w.keyword, t.trademark
FROM words w
JOIN trademarks t ON w.keyword = t.trademark;
```

This will return a list of keyword-trademark pairs where the keyword and trademark are the same. You can then use this list to identify any matches between the words and trademarks tables.

Answer (score -1):

PostgreSQL has good support for regular expressions, which should be able to provide a solution. The relevant operators are described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP). For example, if the requirement is only to match exact words using case-insensitive matching, the following POSIX regex matcher could be used:

`w.keyword ~* CONCAT('([^[:word:]]|^)', t.trademark, '([^[:word:]]|$)')`

This is looking at the single character (if there is one) before and after the word being matched (e.g. `swam`) to make sure neither is a word character. So in the example `while swam is interesting` both such characters would be spaces so it would be a match.

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/oeawfvUf) with some further data added to show which lines get matched (`t` = match, `f` = no match).

*Of course, there are other possible requirements such as partial word matching and case sensitive matching - if this answer doesn't provide a good solution, please let me know in the comments.*