# Optimize query performance for millions of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this PostgreSQL table for storing words:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('processed_words_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
);

insert into words (keyword)
VALUES ('while swam is interesting');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trademarks
(
   id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trademarks_id_seq'::regclass),
   trademark character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
);
```

Into table `trademarks` I will have thousands of registered trademarks names.
I want to compare words stored into `words` table keyword, do they match not only for a words but also for word which is in a group of words. For example:

I have a keyword `while swam is interesting` stored into `words.keyword`. I also have a trademark `swam` located in `trademarks.trademark` I have a word match, so I want to detect this using SQL.

I tried this:

```
select 
    w.id,
    w.keyword,
    t.trademark 
from words w
join trademarks t on t.trademark =
  any(string_to_array(w.keyword, ' '))
where 'all' = any(string_to_array(w.keyword, ' '))
```

The SQL query is implemented properly but execution time is too much. The exception time for table with 30 million of records is 10 seconds. Is there some way to speedup the execution time?

Comment: What about an index? And could you share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement?

Comment: [Full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-intro.html), already suggested to you [last time you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74720114/5298879).

Comment: Thanks but I get error during execution. Can you show me what should be the working query with full text search, please?

Comment: This is what Full Text Search was designed for. It comes free in PostgreSQL, and it's really easy to use.

Comment: Can  you show me updated query please?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index on `words.keyword` which supports the queries with regular expressions :

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS words_keyword ON words USING GIN (keyword gin_trgm_ops);
```

This index should be used by a query like :

```
select 
    w.id,
    w.keyword,
    t.trademark 
from words w
inner join trademarks t
on w.keyword ~ t.trademark
where w.keyword ~ 'all'
```

This should be checked with EXPLAIN ANALYSE for this query.